# What dispatcher i should use in a Struts 2.0.11 based web application?

Tags: java, struts2, dispatcher

I´m developing a web appication based on Struts 2.0.11, Spring and Hibernate.

I don´t know what dispatcher i should declare in web.xml file.

I should use `FilterDispatche`r? Filter Dispatcher + ActionContextCleanUp ?  or StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter? or StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter + ActionContextCleanUp?

Nowadays, the web.xml file contains this code:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>   
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>    
     <filter>
      <filter-name>struts-cleanup</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts-cleanup</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you got out of confusion ?

Comment: Yeah! anyway the application runs at the same way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is enough if we configure FilterDispatcher, for extra features we go for ActionContextCleanUp . Please check the below link for more details
[ActionContextCleanUp](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ActionContextCleanUp.html)

***Edit*** :

> FilterDispatcher has been Deprecated since Struts 2.1.3
>  Since
>   Struts 2.1.3 StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter or StrutsPrepareFilter and
>   StrutsExecuteFilter if needed use ActionContextCleanUp filter in
>   addition to this one

[StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.html)

Comment: Thanks Damodar, And why not use StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter? it seems to be more efficient. Or not?

Comment: please find my EDIT to my answer